# saving and reading array of images with its data in NSUserDefaults or in Document Directory

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to append image with its data in Array after downloading and then try to save in NSUserDefaults. But getting an error. I dont know what is proper way to save and read it .
Can anyone please tell me how i can do this?
Thanks

```
var imgIndex = 0
var imageArray : [UIImage] = []
typealias CompletionHandler = (image: UIImage) -> Void

downloadFileFromURL(NSURL(string: self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String)!, completionHandler:{(img) in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    cell.sideImageView.image = img
                    imageArray.insert(img, atIndex: self.imgIndex) //.append(img)
                    self.imgIndex++
                    print("Image append with data")
                    self.newsDefaults.setObject(imageArray, forKey: "image")

                })
            })


func downloadFileFromURL(url1: NSURL?,completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
    // download code.
    if let url = url1{
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            if data != nil {
                print("image downloaded")
                completionHandler(image: UIImage(data: data!)!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's the error? compile error? runtime? which line?

Comment: this is error 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/kemxK.png

Comment: You should not try to store images (or their data) in user defaults. User defaults is intended for small items, not something as big as an array of images. Better to save the images to your documents directory and then save the paths to those images to user defaults.

Comment: can you tell me how i can save array of images in documents directory? Also i have problem in code, it not append images in array. it gives me error
`fatal error: Array index out of range` I am start appending images from 0 index.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add images to user defaults, they aren't supported. You'll need to convert the image to data and save that instead (either to user defaults or, better, onto disk in a file...

```
imageArray.insert(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.75), atIndex: self.imgIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks but can you please check it in my project. Because it did not appending in sequence. I am getting this error  

`image downloaded
image downloaded
Image append with data
fatal error: Array index out of range`

Comment: that's a different problem because the images download at different speeds so they aren't in order...

Comment: I know but how i can append in order when image download one by one?

Comment: you probably shouldn't, you should use a unique identification scheme and lookup an image for the id (and that id should be used as the file name for the image on disk rather than in user defaults...)